# about function typedef in c++

Tags: c++, function, typedef

```
typedef bool list_less_func (const struct list_elem *a,
                             const struct list_elem *b,
                             void *aux);
```

```
void
list_sort (struct list *list, list_less_func *less, void *aux)
{
  size_t output_run_cnt;        /* Number of runs output in current pass. */

  ASSERT (list != NULL);
  ASSERT (less != NULL);

  /* Pass over the list repeatedly, merging adjacent runs of
     nondecreasing elements, until only one run is left. */
  do
    {
      struct list_elem *a0;     /* Start of first run. */
      struct list_elem *a1b0;   /* End of first run, start of second. */
      struct list_elem *b1;     /* End of second run. */

      output_run_cnt = 0;
      for (a0 = list_begin (list); a0 != list_end (list); a0 = b1)
        {
          /* Each iteration produces one output run. */
          output_run_cnt++;

          /* Locate two adjacent runs of nondecreasing elements
             A0...A1B0 and A1B0...B1. */
          a1b0 = find_end_of_run (a0, list_end (list), less, aux);
          if (a1b0 == list_end (list))
            break;
          b1 = find_end_of_run (a1b0, list_end (list), less, aux);

          /* Merge the runs. */
          inplace_merge (a0, a1b0, b1, less, aux);
        }
    }
  while (output_run_cnt > 1);

  ASSERT (is_sorted (list_begin (list), list_end (list), less, aux));
}
```

```
void wordcount_sort(word_count_list_t *wclist,
                    bool less(const word_count_t *, const word_count_t *)) {
  list_sort(wclist, less_list, less);
}
```

```
static bool less_list(const struct list_elem *ewc1,
                      const struct list_elem *ewc2, void *aux) {
  /* TODO */
    list_less_func* comparefunc;
    if (comparefunc(ewc1, ewc2, aux))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

hey guys I think this is a simple c++ question. problem is in less_list(...)function, it should be about function typedef problem. I'm not familiar with this but my deadline is coming. Thanks for help! And you can ignore most of codes in list_sort, important information is just "less" function.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This question is pretty much questionless, but one problem jumps out at me: `list_less_func* comparefunc;` is a pointer to nowhere.

Comment: it says comparefunc is not initialized

Comment: what do you guys suggest to solve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and post the full verbatim error message. The code should be about 30 lines of code and others should be able to copy and paste it to reproduce the problem. As @user4581301 already said `comparefunc` is an uninitialized pointer. Dereferencing it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: What do you expect `comparefunc(ewc1, ewc2, aux)` to do?

Comment: Please give problem statement

Comment: thank you, I'm trying to post it. I want it to compare the size of two lists and return true if the 1st is smaller and aux is less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling an uninitialized function pointer. That causes undefined behavior. You have to define a function and assign the function's address to the function pointer:

```
struct list_elem {};

typedef bool list_less_func (const list_elem *a,
                             const list_elem *b,
                             void *aux);

list_less_func f;

int main() {
    const list_elem *ewc1 = nullptr;
    const list_elem *ewc2 = nullptr;
    void *aux = nullptr;
    list_less_func* comparefunc = f;
    comparefunc(ewc1, ewc2, aux);
}

bool f (const list_elem *a,
        const list_elem *b,
        void *aux) {
    return a && b && aux;
}
```

The function `f` is just an example. You have to implement a less function.

Unrelated:

Instead of

```
if (comparefunc(ewc1, ewc2, aux))
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

you can write

```
return !comparefunc(ewc1, ewc2, aux);
```